# No endpoint could be found for: direct://DistributeOrderXML, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar

Tags: apache-camel

**DistributeOrderXML.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringRouteContext.xml");

    CamelContext camelContext = SpringCamelContext.springCamelContext(appContext, false);

    try {
        camelContext.start();
        ProducerTemplate orderProducerTemplate = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        InputStream orderInputStream = new FileInputStream(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("order.xml").getFile());
        orderProducerTemplate.sendBody("direct:DistributeOrderXML", orderInputStream);
    } finally {
        camelContext.stop();
    }

}
```

**SpringRouteContext.xml**

```
<camelContext
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:DistributeOrderXML" />
        <log message="Split by Distribute Order" />
        <split>
            <xpath>//order[@product = 'Oil']/items</xpath>
            <to uri="file:src/main/resources/order/" />
            <to uri="stream:out" />
        </split>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

**ERROR CONSOLE**

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[From[direct:DistributeOrderXML] -> [To[stream:... because of No endpoint could be found for: direct://DistributeOrderXML, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:353)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:327)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doInit(AbstractCamelContext.java:2598)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.init(BaseService.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.init(AbstractCamelContext.java:2431)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:111)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2448)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.start(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:420)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at DistributeOrderXML.main(DistributeOrderXML.java:16)

Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: direct://DistributeOrderXML, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:880)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:764)
    at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:57)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.AbstractReifier.resolveEndpoint(AbstractReifier.java:166)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:259)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:117)
    ... 21 more

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Which version of Camel are you using? If it is later than Camel 3, you need to import `camel-direct` in your pom file as the direct component has been moved out of the `camel-core` module.

https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_modularization_of_camel_core

Comment: Hi I use 3.1 to 3.11 and face this issue.Also camel-direct included my pom?

Comment: I'm facing this issue too. And I have the 3.19.0 version with camel-direct included on the pom.xml. What was the solution you found?

Answer (score 0):

I had that error too.
My problem was that I didn't include dependency for the specific Camel component used in my endpoint.

So in this case

> Failed to create route route1:
> Route(route1)[From[direct:DistributeOrderXML] -> [To[**stream:**...

means that Camel cannot recognize "stream:..." as an endpoint.
You have to add this dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
<artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
<version>x.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```